# R: Lapply multiple equality

Tags: r, apply, equality, lapply

Given list `test`, how do I find any numbers that repeat exactly 3 times in `test[[2]]` and 4 times in `test[[3]]`? In this particular example, I want an output that gives me 3 and 6 in [[2]] and 10 in [[3]].

```
test <- list(c(1:10),c(1:10,3,3,6,6),c(1:10,10,10,10))
```

I am able to generate a table for each vector, `test2`.

```
lapply(test,table)
```

But when I tried to equate the table to `1:3`, which I stored as the names of `test`, I get `logical(0)` for each vector.

```
names(test) <- 1:3
lapply(test,function(x) table(x)==names(x))
```

Any idea what went wrong and what the simplest solution is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `lapply(test, names)` you would see that the `names` function applied to each list element just returns NULL. Under the hood I think lapply is just passing the contents of the sublist and not the sublist itself to the function (just like when you use double square brackets to subset - try comparing `names(test[[1]])` to `names(test[1])`).

Using your original idea, if what you want is a vector of logicals, you could try this instead:

```
lapply(1:3, function(x) table(test[x]) == x)
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you. I was trying to make `test` the argument of `lapply` when it's much easier to choose the sublist indices instead.

Comment: @dasf You could also try `lapply(test, function(x) table(x) %in% c(3, 4))`. That would give you the vector of logicals. And to subset that vector you could do `lapply(test, function(x) names(table(x))[table(x) %in% c(3, 4)])`.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a list of table:

```
 tab <- lapply(test, table)
```

To get the number of times `10` appear in each object in the list:

```
lapply(tab, '[', "10")

[[1]]
10 
 1 

[[2]]
10 
 2 

[[3]]
10 
 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you were after with your approach, but this will return the numbers appearing twice:

```
lapply(seq_along(test), function(ii) which(tabulate(test[[ii]]) == ii))
# [[1]]
# integer(0)
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 10
# 
# [[3]]
# integer(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What I'm after is to find any number that repeats twice in `[[2]]` and thrice in `[[3]]`. That the number in both cases happens to be 10 (and only 10) is a coincidence (so is the fact that I want 2x and 3x). Maybe I should change my example to, say, `list(c(1:10),c(1:10,5,5,5),c(1:10,9,9,9,9))`. In that case, the numbers I'm looking for in [[2]] and [[3]] are 5 and 9, and the reps 4 and 5, respectively. I hope this is clearer.

Comment: @dasf see edit. I haven't updated output since I'm AFK